# Drupal 7: How to avoid an infinite loop when translating the contact form path?

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I have three languages set up: English, French and German. To translate the contact form URL, I've done the following for the French language:

- Go to: admin/config/search/path
- Click "Add Alias"
- Language: select "French"
- Existing system path: enter "contact"
- Path alias: enter "contactez-nous"
- Save

This is working fine. Then I'm trying to do the same for German using the "kontakt" path alias, but each time I go to the translated path (/de/kontakt) I see the following message:

> Oops, looks like this request tried to create an infinite loop. We do
>   not allow such things here. We are a professional website!

This doesn't happen for the French language.

As I've setup the French language a long time ago, perhaps another step is involved but I can't figure it. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed on production site: this only happened on staging environment but I still can't understand why!